# Can PDO connections be maintained between classes?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I'm attempting to make a simple query library and I'm using PDO for database access.

Let's say I have the following two classes:

```
class FirstClass {
    var $dbh;

    function __construct($host,$dbname,$user,$pw) {
        $this->dbh = new PDO ("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pw);
    }

    function use_second($foo) {
        return new SecondClass ($foo,$this->dbh);
    }
}

class SecondClass {
    function __construct($foo, $dbh) {
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM atable WHERE bar = :foo');
        $sth = $sth->execute(array('foo'=>$foo));
        // do something with the query
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to use the same PDO connection between classes? - Because I seem to be having some issues with this, for example, if I `var_dump` my connection from the second class, I get:

```
object(PDO)#2 (0) { }
```

Surely that isn't right?

Also if I run a select query, and then dump the `$sth` variable, I just get:

```
bool(true)
```

Is this because I am handling the connection incorrectly? - If so how can I properly use the same connection between classes?

Comment: Answering the question from the title: yes, they can.

Comment: Yes of cause you can. You could have saved yours and our time by just trying it before asking.

Comment: Um... I mentioned in the question that I've tried this. I said that I didn't believe it was working correctly and was wondering whether my handling of the connection was causing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens, because you overwrite `$sth`, which was your statement, but now is a boolean:

```
class SecondClass {
    function __construct($foo, $dbh) {
        // returns PDOStatement:
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM atable WHERE bar = :foo');
        // returns boolean:
        $sth = $sth->execute(array('foo'=>$foo));
        // do something with the query
    }
}
```

To correct it, just do not overwrite `$sth`, so you are able to fetch results from it:

```
class SecondClass {
    function __construct($foo, $dbh) {
        // returns PDOStatement:
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM atable WHERE bar = :foo');
        // returns boolean:
        $success = $sth->execute(array('foo'=>$foo));
        // do something with the query
        if ($success) {
            // do something with $sth->fetchAll() or $sth->fetch(), or anything
            $all_the_results = $sth->fetchAll();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer is the only one which *actually* explains the issue - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).  It returns a boolean.  The fact that `sth` winds up at `true` means that the query succeeded.

Your design is a bit shaky because you're creating objects in non-factory methods of other objects, which can be confusing.  Ideally, all of your objects will be created at the start of the controller's execution, and injected into the other objects that need them (e.g. the `PDO` object would be created outside of `FirstClass::__construct`, and you would have something like `__construct(PDO $db)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would simply ask (by asking I mean is set the prequists) for the ready PDO object.

```
function __construct($dbh) {
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
}
```

This way you get a cleaner approach on what your object needs (it doesn't need a user/password etc, it needs a database connection!)

It also eliminates the need for the abstraction class (FirstClass), as you can go directly to the second class.